# Different result in Cell and Name Manager with same formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

My formula is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((OFFSET(sheet1!$A$1,ROW(sheet1!dynamic_cell_anchor),0,1,1000)<>"")*COLUMN(OFFSET(sheet1!$A$1,ROW(sheet1!dynamic_cell_anchor),0,1,1000))))
```

which can directly return the right result(the largest non-blank column number in that range) in **CELL**.

BUT when this same formula was firstly defined in **Name Manager** then be loaded by its name in **CELL**, it would show as `#VALUE!` in **CELL**.

---

I checked both by **Evaluate Formula**, They show different middle step:

Directly in **CELL**,

```
SUMPRODUCT(MAX((OFFSET(sheet1!$A$1,30,0,1,1000)<>"")*COLUMN(OFFSET(sheet1!$A$1,ROW(sheet1!dynamic_cell_anchor),0,1,1000))))
```

Defined in **Name Manager** firstly,

```
SUMPRODUCT(MAX((OFFSET(sheet1!$A$1,{30},0,1,1000)<>"")*COLUMN(OFFSET(sheet1!$A$1,ROW(sheet1!dynamic_cell_anchor),0,1,1000))))
```

Obviously, a pair of curly brackets affects the result.

Buy why?  and How can this be solved?  (I prefer to define it in Name Manager.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping `ROW(sheet1!dynamic_cell_anchor)` in `SUM` i.e.

```
SUM(ROW(sheet1!dynamic_cell_anchor))
```